# Cannot get INSTALL-project of VTK-Solution compiled

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, vtk

### I am trying to get VTK by going through
https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build#On_Windows
So after the VTK-Source I downloaded  cMake and used it to create a Visual-Studio-Solution.
But building the INSTALL-project in Visual Studio 2019 fails with error code MSB3073. I found out that the command

```
setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=$(Configuration) -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal &amp; call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% &amp; goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
```

---

which is in INSTALL.vcxproj causes this error. When running it in a command shell it returns: "CMake Error: Error processing file: cmake_install.cmake".
I do understand that since I only can find a file  …vtk\src\Utilities\Doxygen\doc_makeall.cmake.in Shouldn’t there be a file “doc_makeall.cmake”, if cMake puts such a command into the project file?
Visual Studio is running with administrator-rights.
Does anybody have any idea on how to get VTK’s INSTALL-project compiled?
Thanks a lot in advance!!
Jürgen